# How can I use method of an ObjC class which contains a forward declare Swift class in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, forward-declaration

```
//CoolSwiftClass.swift
@objc(MyCoolSwiftClass)
class CoolSwiftClass: NSObject {}

//MyObjCViewController.h
@class MyCoolSwiftClass;
@interface MyObjCViewController : UIViewController
- (instancetype)initWithMyCoolSwiftClass:(MyCoolSwiftClass *)myCoolSwiftClassInstance;
@end

//SadSwiftClass.swift
class SadSwiftClass: UIViewController {
  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    //This won't work
    let myObjCViewController = MyObjCViewController(coolSwiftClass: coolSwiftClassInstance)
  }
}
```

It seems that Swift can find the forward declaration `MyCoolSwiftClass` but it cannot find out that it's actually the `CoolSwiftClass`.

[image: screenshot]

And I didn't find anything that can help me in [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

**Update at 2015-11-19 13:34 CST**

Just upload a repo to GitHub: [SO33775908](https://github.com/puttin/SO33775908)

**Update at 2015-11-19 13:47 CST**

Just find out a workaround:

No special ObjC name. Checkout branch [No special ObjC name](https://github.com/puttin/SO33775908/tree/Workaround1)

**Update at 2015-11-19 14:47 CST**

Another workaround which generate warnings:

[@compatibility_alias with several warnings](https://github.com/puttin/SO33775908/tree/Workaround2)

Comment: `And I didn't find anything that can help me in Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project.` – are you serious? There's a whole section about importing Swift into Objective-C and the solution to your problem is stated in the very first paragraph...

Comment: @akashivskyy Yes, I tried some solutions that seems help but failed.

Comment: Let me quote the specific part then – `When you import Swift code into Objective-C, you rely on an Xcode-generated header file to expose those files to Objective-C. This automatically generated file is an Objective-C header that declares the Swift interfaces in your target. It can be thought of as an umbrella header for your Swift code. The name of this header is your product module name followed by adding "-Swift.h".`

Comment: @akashivskyy It seems that you don't understand what I ask. I have that umbrella header. I may upload a repo to prove.

Comment: Please clarify then :)

Comment: @akashivskyy just upload the repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I ever found is the workaround 1:

**No special ObjC name**

And if you have used that special ObjC name for a while, you can use something like this:

```
//ClassName_Alias.h
#define MyCoolSwiftClass CoolSwiftClass

//CoolSwiftClass.swift
@objc
class CoolSwiftClass: NSObject {}
```

Please checkout Question Update 1 for the sample repo.